# How to authenticate Bitstamp HTTP API v2 request using OpenAPI specification

Tags: c#, authentication, httprequest

I am using OpenAPI specification that I got from https://www.bitstamp.net/api/
I used a tool called NSWAG to generate the client for me.

I can't seem to authenticate with it, keep getting the following error. I have looked at so many examples but I can't seem to to get it to work.

> The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (403).
>
> Status: 403
> Response:
> {"status": "error", "reason": "Invalid signature", "code": "API0005"}

***BitstampClient.cs***

```
public partial class BitstampClient
{
    private readonly string key;
    private readonly string secret;
    private readonly bool isPublicApi;
    
    public BitstampClient(string key, string secret, IHttpClientFactory httpFactory) : this(httpFactory.CreateClient($"BitstampClient-{key}"))
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.isPublicApi = false;
    }
    
    public BitstampClient(IHttpClientFactory httpFactory) : this(httpFactory.CreateClient($"BitstampClient-Public"))
    {
        this.isPublicApi = true;
    }
    
    public BitstampClient(string key, string secret) : this(new HttpClient())
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.secret = secret;
    }
    
    partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, StringBuilder urlBuilder)
    {
        if (!this.isPublicApi)
        {
            var xauth = $"{"BITSTAMP"} {this.key}";
            var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  //DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var time = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            var version = "v2";
            var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var signature = GetXAuthSignature(nonce, this.key, this.secret, "QWERTY");

            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth", xauth);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Signature", signature);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Nonce", nonce.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Timestamp", time.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Version", version);

            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = null;
        }
    }

    private string GetXAuthSignature(string nonce, string key, string secret, string clientId)
    {
        var msg = $"{nonce}{clientId}{key}";
        return ByteArrayToString(SignHMACSHA256(secret, StringToByteArray(msg))).ToUpper();
    }
    
    private static byte[] SignHMACSHA256(string key, byte[] data)
    {
        var hashMaker = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
        return hashMaker.ComputeHash(data);
    }

    private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
    }
    
    private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] hash)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to thank you for giving me a heads start on this issue. With the example that you have provided I was able to get started with the `bitstamp API`..

The class I ended up with is:

```
public partial class BitstampClient
{
    private readonly string publicKey;
    private readonly string secretKey;
    private readonly bool isPublicApi;

    public BitstampClient(string publicKey, string secretKey, HttpClient client) : this(client)
    {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
        this.isPublicApi = false;
    }

    partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, string url)
    {
        if (!this.isPublicApi)
        {
            string apiKey = $"BITSTAMP {this.publicKey}";
            string timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();
            string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string contentType = string.Empty;
            string version = "v2";
            string payloadString = string.Empty;

            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = null;

                var payload = request.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
                {
                    //contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    contentType = "application/json";
                    payloadString = payload;
                }
            }

            url = url.Replace("https://", string.Empty).Replace("http://", string.Empty);
            var signature = $"{apiKey}{request.Method}{url}{contentType}{nonce}{timestamp}{version}{payloadString}";

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)))
            {
                byte[] rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature));
                signature = BitConverter.ToString(rawHmac).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }

            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth", apiKey);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Signature", signature);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Nonce", nonce);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Timestamp", timestamp);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Version", version);
            //request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);

            //request.Content = null;
        }
    }

    public virtual Task<TradingPairsInfoResponse[]> GetTradingPairsInfoAsync2()
    {
        return GetTradingPairsInfoAsync2(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }

    [GenerateGenericOverride(nameof(GetTradingPairsInfoAsync))]
    public partial Task<TradingPairsInfoResponse[]> GetTradingPairsInfoAsync2(CancellationToken cancellationToken);  
}
```

invoked with

```
            string key = "";
            string secret = "";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var client = new BitstampClient(key, secret, httpClient);

            var accountBalance = await client.GetAccountBalancesAsync();

            var transactions = await client.GetOHLCDataAsync(Step._60, 100, null, null, null, market_symbol: "btcusd");

            //var pairs = await client.GetTradingPairsInfoAsync(); // not working
            var pairs = await client.GetTradingPairsInfoAsync2();
```

please take caution when using the raw `OpenAPI` specification of `bitstamp` as it's corrupted.. For example, there is a section:

```
"OrderTransaction": {
        "properties": {
          "tid": {
            "description": "Transaction ID.",
            "example": 1,
            "format": "int32",
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "price": {
            "description": "Price.",
            "example": "100.00",
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "{from_currency}": {
            "description": "{from_currency} amount.",
            "example": "101.00",
            "readOnly": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
```

which produces broken C# client code as below:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// {from_currency} amount.
        /// </summary>

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("{from_currency}")]

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore(Condition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string {from_currency
    } { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// {to_currency} amount.
/// </summary>

[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("{to_currency}")]

[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore(Condition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
public string
{ to_currency}
{ get; set; }
```

**you are not mentioning this in your initial post, so I really want to know how you've fixed this problem. I ended up manually updating the client code after the generation.**

Another note to take - at least one of the endpoints is not returning the correct data type. For example the endpoint `GetTradingPairsInfoAsync` returns an object of type `TradingPairsInfoResponse`, which is according to spec here:

```
    "/api/v2/trading-pairs-info/": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Return trading pairs info.",
        "operationId": "GetTradingPairsInfo",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TradingPairsInfoResponse"
                }
              }
            },
            "description": "Get operation"
          }
        },
        "security": [],
        "summary": "Trading pairs info",
        "tags": [
          "Market info"
        ]
      }
    },
```

however you will end up with deserialization error upon calling `await client.GetTradingPairsInfoAsync();`. The correct response type is an array of objects `TradingPairsInfoResponse[]`.. I am not sure is there are other broken endpoints in the spec.. I have come up with some fixes by creating a source generator that overrides the generic type. You can read more on this topic in my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704287/overriding-method-generic-with-design-time-code-generation/77707450#77707450).

Please let me know in the comments the experience that you've had with the spec and how you've solved the above issues :)

Comment: Hi, sorry only saw your message now. I did come right yes.  I also saw the file was corrupted and manually fixed it. But the ran into weird issues. Can't remember what they were now. But in the end I just ended up creating my own client. I can send you a gist of the code if you'd like.

Comment: Hey @R4nc1d i'm also trying to generate a client to get some bitstamp data, running into all the same problems you did
if you'd be able to upload somewhere the whole fixed generated client code, I would really really appreciate it!!

Comment: @DanielPerez please see the Gist - https://gist.github.com/r4nc1d/a24d7b4baabb7857cc41e46d082b2009

Comment: thanks a lot! will take a look and revert

Comment: @R4nc1d I´ve ported the code but there´s a few classes missing, not sure if you got some autogenerated and forgot to add to the gist?
I tried generating manually and then running but got an exception (404 not found), 

```var client = new BitstampClient(_appConfig.Value.BitstampConfig.PublicApiKey,
            _appConfig.Value.BitstampConfig.PrivateApiKey, new HttpClientFactory());
        var result = await client.GetAccountBalancesForCurrencyAsync("EUR", new CancellationToken());```

Comment: EDIT: forget it, changed to "eur" instead of "EUR" and it works. API is not very user friendly with their error messages..

still would need those extra classes like ErrorResponse because i'm not able to deserialize correctly the response though

Comment: Hey Daniel no worries, i didn't add all the classes as there are just way to many. But ill gladly try and add the rest if you dont come right. And yes there API is not friendly at all. I remember i had issues with the Errors as all their Responses returns a status 200. So had to handle them differently.

Comment: no worries, I managed to circumvent the issue with a few changes to the code. thanks for all the help! and agree that the API is quite poor