# overriding method generic with design time code generation

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-generation

I would like to ask a rather generic question about the problem that I would like to solve with code generators (or some other approach) in C# and I would like to know whether it's at all possible to do it with such method..

The problem I am struggling is - there is a thirt party API that exposes `OpenAPI` specification. I am using the `nswag studio` to generate a C# client code.

The problem is that the the specification seems to contain invalid data in it. So rather than depending on the third-party api provider to fix the problem (which I have reported already) - I would like to solve the problem in my own way..

The problem comes from the method that retrieves the data from the API endpoint and looks like this (simplified version):

```
public virtual async Task<SomeResponseType> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  var response = GetResponse();
  return ParseResponse<SomeResponseType>(resonse);
}
```

the problem is the return type. The correct type is an array of objects, i.e. `SomeResponseType[]`, otherwise I am getting the JSON deserialization exception.

Given that I don't want to rewrite the whole method every time there is a specification error - I would like the C# to generate such methods for me!

The solution that I am seeking (I think) must do something with code generation.

Is it somehow possible for the compiler to generate me a method override that would take in a given type override, over the default type? e.g.

```
public virtual async Task<SomeResponseType[]> GetDataAsync2(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  var response = GetResponse();
  return ParseResponse<SomeResponseType[]>(response);
}
```

theoretically, with code gens - is it possible to create a new method and mark it with an attribute, for the code gen logic to pick it up and generate the code based on the original method? Something along these lines should trigger the generation, where `GetDataAsync` parameter is the method to use as a base..

```
    [CodeGen("GetDataAsync")]
    public partial Task<TradingPairsInfoResponse[]> GetDataAsync2(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Any ideas, comments and tips are welcomed..

I apologize in advance.. I've never used code generators, so I have no idea what they are capable of. Would like to lean from the community, before I sink 4 hours into the topic and realize that the problem I am trying to solve is not solvable in such a way...

using `.net7 +`

Answer (score 1):

After studying the topic and countless experiments I was able to create a source generator. The aim was to make something that works first, so there are a bunch of improvements and optimizations that could be made to the code below so if you plan on using it - please retest and adjust accordingly to your needs

`NswagGeneratedClient`

```
public partial class NswagGeneratedClient
{
    [GenerateGenericOverride(nameof(GetDataAsync))]           
    public partial Task<DataType[]> GetDataAsync2(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Attribute accepts mandatory parameter - the method name that we are targeting. Basically what is going to happen - is the new method is going to be generated, but the generic of the target method will be replaced by the generic provided in the new partial method.

`GenerateGenericOverrideAttribute`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class GenerateGenericOverrideAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public string MethodName { get; }

    public GenerateGenericOverrideAttribute(string methodName)
    {
        MethodName = methodName;
    }
}
```

`AugmentingGenerator` - resides in separate source generator .net standard library. Look this topic up on the internet for more details. Otherwise the post will be few times larger.

```
namespace ClientGenerator;

[Generator]
public class AugmentingGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        MySyntaxReceiver syntaxReceiver = (MySyntaxReceiver)context.SyntaxReceiver;
        if (syntaxReceiver == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(syntaxReceiver.ClassName))
            return;

        bool isShouldStop = false;
        MethodDeclarationSyntax targetMethod = null;
        foreach (var tree in context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees)
        {
            var treeRoot = tree.GetRoot();
            if (treeRoot == null) 
                continue;

            foreach (var node in treeRoot.ChildNodes().OfType<BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax>())
            {
                var nsName = GetName(node);
                if (nsName != syntaxReceiver.NamespaceName)
                    continue;

                foreach (var node2 in node.ChildNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>())
                {
                    var cName = GetName(node2);
                    if (cName != syntaxReceiver.ClassName)
                        continue;

                    foreach (var node3 in node2.ChildNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>())
                    {
                        var mName = GetName(node3);
                        if (mName != syntaxReceiver.OldMethodName)
                            continue;

                        var gName = GetGenericName(node3);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gName))
                            continue;

                        var parameters = GetParameters(node3);
                        var methodParameters = string.Join(",", parameters);
                        if (methodParameters != syntaxReceiver.MethodParameters)
                            continue;

                        targetMethod = node3;

                        isShouldStop = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (isShouldStop)
                        break;
                }

                if (isShouldStop)
                    break;
            }

            if (isShouldStop)
                break;
        }

        if (targetMethod == null)
            return;

        var oldGenericName = GetGenericName(targetMethod);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldGenericName))
            return;

        var targetMethodCode = targetMethod.GetText().ToString();
        targetMethodCode = targetMethodCode.Replace(syntaxReceiver.OldMethodName, syntaxReceiver.NewMethodName);
        targetMethodCode = targetMethodCode.Replace(oldGenericName, syntaxReceiver.NewGenericName);
        targetMethodCode = targetMethodCode.Replace("public virtual", "public partial");

        SourceText sourceText = SourceText.From($@"
namespace {syntaxReceiver.NamespaceName};

public partial class {syntaxReceiver.ClassName}
{{
    {targetMethodCode}
}}", Encoding.UTF8);
        context.AddSource($"{syntaxReceiver.ClassName}.Generated.cs", sourceText);
    }

    public static string GetName(TypeDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        return node.Identifier.ValueText?.Trim();
    }

    public static string GetName(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        return node.Identifier.ValueText?.Trim();
    }
    
    public static string GetGenericName(MemberDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var sn = node as SyntaxNode;
        var cn = sn.ChildNodes().OfType<QualifiedNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (cn != null)
        {
            sn = cn;
        }

        var omgn = sn.ChildNodes().OfType<GenericNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (omgn == null)
            return "";

        return omgn.TypeArgumentList.GetText().ToString().Trim();
    }

    public static string GetName(BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        string result = "";

        var nsIdentifer = node.ChildNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (nsIdentifer == null)
            return result;

        return nsIdentifer.Identifier.ValueText?.Trim();
    }

    public static List<string> GetParameters(MemberDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        var sss = node.ChildNodes().OfType<ParameterListSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (sss == null || sss.Parameters == null || sss.Parameters.Count == 0)
            return result;

        foreach (var parameter in sss.Parameters)
        {
            var sn = parameter as SyntaxNode;
            var cn = sn.ChildNodes().OfType<QualifiedNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (cn != null)
            {
                sn = cn;
            }

            var identifier = sn.ChildNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (identifier == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
                
            var parameterType = identifier.Identifier.ValueText;
            result.Add(parameterType);
        }

        return result;
    }

    class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
    {
        public string NamespaceName { get; private set; }
        public string ClassName { get; private set; }
        public string NewMethodName { get; private set; }
        public string NewGenericName { get; private set; }
        public string OldMethodName { get; private set; }
        public string MethodParameters { get; private set; }

        public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
        {
            if (syntaxNode is MethodDeclarationSyntax mds)
            {
                var attribute = mds.AttributeLists.SelectMany(al => al.Attributes)
                        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.GetText().ToString() == "GenerateGenericOverride");

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    string newMethodName = GetName(mds);

                    var newGenericName = GetGenericName(mds);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGenericName))
                        return;

                    //int counter = 0;
                    var oldMethodName = "";
                    var arguments = attribute.ArgumentList?.Arguments;
                    foreach (var syntax in arguments)
                    {
                        oldMethodName = syntax.Expression.ToString();
                        oldMethodName = GetStringBetween(oldMethodName, "\"", "\"");
                        oldMethodName = GetStringBetween(oldMethodName, "(", ")");

                        break;
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldMethodName))
                        return;

                    var classNode = mds.Parent;
                    if (classNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds)
                    {
                        string className = GetName(cds);

                        var nsNode = cds.Parent;
                        if (nsNode is FileScopedNamespaceDeclarationSyntax nsds)
                        {
                            string namespaceName = GetName(nsds);
                            var parameters = GetParameters(mds);

                            NamespaceName = namespaceName;
                            ClassName = className;
                            NewMethodName = newMethodName;
                            NewGenericName = newGenericName;
                            OldMethodName = oldMethodName;
                            MethodParameters = string.Join(",", parameters);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string GetStringBetween(string original, string start, string end)
        {
            int startIndex = original.IndexOf(start);
            if (startIndex == -1)
            {
                return original;
            }

            startIndex += start.Length;
            int endIndex = original.IndexOf(end, startIndex);
            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                return original;
            }

            return original.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggested changes to generator code are welcomed. Since it's my first generator I am satisfied with the result for now..

**Edit 23.12.2023** added method parameter matching. Now the new and the "old" methods must have the exact same set of arguments for the generation logic to work.. I've also added loop abortion logic to improve the processing time.